# How to set the default sorting column for lists?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a list of record.

Its model has this

```
protected static function booted()
{
    static::addGlobalScope(new OrderByDescriptionScope);
}
```

this scope is doing

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    $builder->orderBy('descrizione', 'asc');
}
```

but when opening a list, records are never sorted by `descrizione`.

This is the suggested method of apply a global scope, as for laravel 8 documentation.

**Why does my code not work?**

**How to set default sorting for laravel backpack?**

Comment: perhaps sir this might be helpful `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59759004/how-to-sort-global-scope-by-attribute-laravel`

Comment: It is exactly what I've done - Why doesn't it work ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using crud object, you can sort your recodes using `orderBy` method, for example:

```
 public function setupListOperation()
    {
    $this->crud->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $collect_all = $collect_all->sortByDesc("id");

    $collect_all->values()->all();
```

when you fetch data after order like this.

Comment: Is this specific to backpack for Laravel? if yes, where do I put this code? and why my code doesn't work? - Please note : i do not downvoted your answer.

Comment: when you get data if it's like                                                                        
$product = Product::query()->where("id", "=", 3)->get(); after                       
$product = $product->sortByDesc("id");                                                  
$product->values->all(); /// it'is simple query for example. you can use this method complex queries.